# replacing '==' with 'in' operator in if conditions

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

When I started to traverse a code of my friend, I came across two declarations of if clause.

one is declared as follows:

(CASE A)

```
if x not in ('a', 'b'):
    pass
```

another is declared like this:

(CASE B)

```
 if x != 'a' or x != 'b':
        pass
```

(CASE C)

```
if x != 'a' and x != 'b':
    pass
```

I've simplified the values as 'a' and 'b' but the actual values are complicated and pretty long. When I run them separately, I got the same output.

Which one does CASE A match with? CASE B or CASE C.
Also which form of writing is correct? using in or using equality operator.

Comment: Can you think of a false condition for case B? Can you think of a false condition for Case A?

Comment: I've already tried different combinations of values for the conditions. They all work. My question is 'is it okay to leave it with CASE A or to convert to case B or CASE C'

Comment: Use the values of 'a', 'b', and some other value (i dunno, 'c'?), and try it out! What do you get for the conditional in case a, b, and c? What could you give case b to make the conditional evaluate to `False`?

Both forms are correct. Depending on the nature of the data you may prefer one to the other, but both are perfectly valid.

Comment: "I've already tried different combinations of values for the conditions. " what value of x would make condition B false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They not the same, if you start from Case A, hopefully it is easy to see.

Consider case A.

```
x not in ('a', 'b')
```

This literally means, x is not equal to 'a' and x is not equal to 'b'. Or written as code.

```
x != 'a' and x != 'b'
```

That happens to be case C.

Case B on the other hand is *exactly the same as C but it has an 'or' instead of an 'and'.*

'or' does not perform the same operation as 'and', therefore case C is different.

```
x = 'a'
print("A", x not in ('a', 'b') )
print("B", x != 'a' or x != 'b')
print("C", x != 'a' and x != 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

In `or` statement you are saying that if you found any of the operands true then no need to check the other operands because the result will be true anyway.

In CASE B if `x` was (not 'a') then it's true and it'll not check if `x` is equals to 'b'.

You can simply test the cases by printing `x` as follows:

```
>>> x='b'
>>> if x not in ('a', 'b'): #CASE A (nothing printed when x='b')
...     print(x)
...
>>> if x != 'a' or x!='b': #CASE B
...     print(x)
...
b  # The condition is true so x's value printed
>>> if x != 'a' and x!='b': #CASE C (nothing printed when x='b')
...     print(x)
...
>>>
```

Here you can find that A and C have the same output (which is nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, CASE C.

`x not in ('a', 'b')` means that x has not been appeared in given elements.

CASE B can be converted into correct form with:

```
if not (x == 'a' or x == 'b'):
    pass
```